# MySQL row selection

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table as below,

```
 ID     Name       Age
 ----------------------
  100       A         10
  203       B         20
```

Now how do i select only row1 using MySQL SELECT command and then I've to increase +1 to it to select row2. In short I'll be using for loop to do certain operations.

Thanks.

Comment: This is covered in every basic "PHP and databases" tutorial, is it not?

Comment: Will mysql_fetch_row help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've got a mix up. You want to *select* all the rows you want to iterate through in your for loop with your query, and then iterate through them one by one using php's mysql functions like [mysql_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to use tables in a linear fashion like this. Set your criteria, sorting as appropriate, and then to select the next row use your existing criteria and limit it to one row.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `ID` LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `ID` WHERE ID > 100 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off retrieving all rows that you need, then using this. Note the LIMIT is entirely optional.

```
$query = mysql_query(' SELECT ID, Name, Age FROM table_name WHERE condition LIMIT max_number_you_want '))
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)
{
    // Do stuff
    // $row['ID'], $row['Name'], $row['Age']
}
```

Lots of small queries to the database will execute much slower than one decent-sized one.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the result into an array (php.net : mysql_fetch_*).
And after you'll can loop on the array "to do certain operations"

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is a pretty common thing to do in PHP.  Like the others who have posted, here is my version (using objects instead of arrays):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
  // Results are now in the $row variable.
  // ex:  $row->ID, $row->Name, $row->Age
}
```